# Android - unable to play song on splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

im trying to put sound when splash screen open up, but the song.start() returns me nullpointerexception. Why is this happen? im using min api 11.

code :

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

MediaPlayer song;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bg);

    song = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashmusic);
    song.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){//create thread to execute one class to another class within a time
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);//5 seconds of pausing
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMain = new Intent("com.example.hapshare.DashboardActivity"); 
                startActivity(openMain);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    song.release();
    finish();
}
```

Logcat :

```
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hapshare/com.example.hapshare.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
11-19 09:42:02.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide the sound file you're trying to play.  If you have the wrong media format, create will return null, have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: I don't think that is the entire log. There should be a "caused by" part

Comment: thanks @david99world i solved my problem once i convert the music file to mp3 =)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your MediaPlayer is not created correctly (from the docs for MediaPlayer create()):

> Returns
>   a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed

so check your R.raw.splashmusic

From the docs again:

> In this case, a "raw" resource is a file that the system does not try to parse in any particular way. However, the content of this resource should not be raw audio. It should be a properly encoded and formatted media file in one of the supported formats.

You can also create MediaPlayer object this way:

```
try {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.splashmusic);

    song = new MediaPlayer();
    song.reset();
    song.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
    song.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    song.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

    song.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Remember though, that prepare() might take long, so it's not good idea to create MediaPlayer on your UI thread. You have 2 choices here:

- create another thread and spawn MP there
- use prepareAsync(), and when preparation is finished, onPrepared() method of the MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, configured through setOnPreparedListener() is called.

Please read more about MediaPlayer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Also, when creating intent, instead of:

```
Intent openMain = new Intent("com.example.hapshare.DashboardActivity");
```

do this:

```
Intent openMain = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong media type, check the media types available `developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html` as this would cause `MediaPlayer.create` to return null.